# Race conditions in Puppeteer/Jest tests in Docker

Tags: docker, jestjs, puppeteer, race-condition

I have written a large test using jest & puppeteer that does a whole bunch of stuff in my application.

When I run the test locally - everything passes 99% of the time.

When I run the test in Docker - the test inconsistently fails in multiple places. Almost every time I run the test, it usually fails while waiting for a selector to load.

I unfortunately cannot share my code on here but I can however show what I have done to mitigate failure based on the reasearch I've done.

1. placing `waitFor(< x ms>)` calls after a navigation has a occurred or before assertions
2. implementing the `Promise.all` pattern as suggested in the [puppeteer docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) for click events. Something like this:

```
async singleClickElement(selector, page) {
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        page.waitForSelector(selector),
        page.click(selector)
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

3. messing around with the `sloMo` settings (seems like 17 is the most successful number for me, considering our default css transitions are .4s)
4. using `screenshots` to take a before/after pics in places where the test fails

**Some Edits I forgot to mention**

5. my args `--forceExit  --runInBand --detectOpenHandles`
6. my timeout is increased to a min `jest.setTimeout(60000)`
7. browser args `'--window-size=2560,1080', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--enable-logging=stderr', '--v=1'`

I am running out of ideas and looking for suggestions as to how I can mitigate race conditions in Docker when running UI tests. Please feel free to suggest anything that you think might help me. Thanks :D

Comment: I know this question is a little old but I am experience the exact same behavior! I have tried every combination you pointed out as well, including trying many different flavors of docker images, both prebuilt (such as the buildkite one) and rolling my own.

I have also tried both mocha and jest and both exhibit the same behavior, which leads me to believe it is inherent within puppeteer. Were you ever able to solve this issue?

Comment: @JohnZoidbergMD check my answer below, hope it helps you, cheers

Answer (score 2):

After months of more trial and error, I think I have found some great ways to run Jest and Puppeteer in Docker with minimal to no fails.

**Solution #1: Waiting for HTTP responses when loading pages/components**

Puppeteer comes out of the box with `waitForResponse` function that allows the browser to wait for some response to come back form the server. In Chrome dev tools, have a look at `Network` and reload the page you are on and wait for responses.

Example: let's say I am loading some page and I am waiting for a response from the server to contain some information about an array of brands. When I navigate to that page I will call

```
await page.waitForResponse(res => res.url().includes('brands'));
```

and only after I received this response, I can proceed with my test. I find this works quiet well for out of all the other methods.

*Note: your response might come at diff intervals at every page reload. Ex, my brands response comes as fast 300ms and as slow as 900ms. **Try finding a response either that comes from the server with data OR the most commonly occurring last response (reload 10 times and watch)***

[image: Example of server response in chrome]

**Solution #2: Checking for a property of some element before proceeding**

Let's say your page will first load a button. Once you click on that button, another button should appear after a small transition of .5 secs. **You can check the text content of the button** before proceeding.

[`.$eval` docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)

```
const saveBtn = await page.$eval('.btn-selector', btn => btn.textContent);
        if (saveBtn.includes('Save')) {
    ...
    }
```

You can also **check whether the selected value of a dropdown appeared in the DOM** after you clicked it.

[`.$` docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pageselector)

```
        const brandsSelector = await page.$('select:nth-child(1)');
        const brandsSelectedValue = await page.evaluate(brandsSelector => brandsSelector.options[brandsSelector.selectedIndex].value, brandsSelector);
```

**Solution #3: long `waitFor` calls**

Sometimes the above two solutions just aren't enough and your only way to get past some tough point is to call a long `waitFor`

```
await page.waitFor(3000);
```

I generally try to avoid these but sometimes it's the only thing that gets my tests to pass and work properly against a staged testing server in Docker.

**Solution #4: `visible` property when using `waitForSelector`**

Sometimes simple things like `waitForSelector` functions can be overlooked because they are so obvious yet this function take an `options` object to which you can pass

```
await page.waitForSelector('.selector', {visible: true});
```

This waits for some element in your page to be visible first before doing anything else to it.

**Solution #5: Check your cloud provider's loads**

If you are using AWS for example, make sure your instance has a high enough capacity of requests it can make per some time period. My staged tests were crashing until an AWS load was maximised to take on a greater number of requests per second which allowed some intermittent failures to subside.

**Solution #6: Use all of these solutions together (obviously)**

Good luck, end-to-end testing can be painful when testing in diff environments, especially staged servers.